# passing a result set from a user defined function into the max() function

Tags: max, user-defined-functions, xslt-3.0

first time poster long time browser to bear with me if I'm not clear. I'm quite new to xslt.
I'm trying to write a function which passes a list of cleansed date values to the max() function. Following is my input document:

```
<dates>
    <date>1990-09-02Z</date>
    <date>1990-09-03Z</date>
    <date>1990-09-04Z</date>
    <date>1990-09-05Z</date>
    <date>1990-09-06Z</date>
</dates>
```

As you can see, the string values have a trailing 'Z'. If I try to pass these directly to max() using a nested substring() function

```
<xsl:template match="/dates">
    <xsl:value-of select="max(xs:date(substring(//date,1,10)))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I get this error:

> A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the first argument of fn:substring() ("1990-09-02Z", "1990-09-03Z")

so I've included an xsl:function declaration into my stylesheet which now looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:test="http://www.blah.blah/funct"
    version="3.0">


<xsl:function name="test:funct" visibility="public">
<xsl:param name="input"/>

<xsl:sequence>  
   <xsl:for-each select="$input">
      <xsl:value-of select="xs:date(substring(.,1,10))"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:sequence>

</xsl:function>    


<xsl:template match="/dates">
    <xsl:value-of select="max(test:funct(//date))"/>
</xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, now I'm getting the following error

> Failure converting {1990-09-02} to a number

I thought max() could handle dates? I'm quite confused about what's being passed into the max() function and why it's not working. the output I'm looking for is **1990-09-06**

I try to read the w3org specification docs but the terms are too technical for me so not making sense of it. Appreciate any help you can offer.

By the way, processing engine I'm using is Saxon-PE 9.8.0.12

edit: my ultimate goal is to have a stylesheet with a list of functions which I can include within other xsl stylesheets, so ultimately the solution has to be a function. In this specific case a function which produces a list of cleansed dates which can then be passed to max().

Answer (score 1):

As you have tagged that as XSLT 3, I would suggest to start with basic XPath 2/3 where you can simply write

```
//date/xs:date(substring(., 1, 10))
```

i.e. you can use function calls in the last step of your path to extract the substring and construct an `xs:date`: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexjii

So that expression `//date/xs:date(substring(., 1, 10))` gives you a sequence of `xs:date` values, you can then use the `max` function on them:

```
max(//date/xs:date(substring(., 1, 10)))
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexjii/1

As for writing a user-defined function to have that last step done, I would write a function where the input is an `xs:string` and which returns an `xs:date`:

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:date" as="xs:date">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="xs:date(substring($input, 1, 10))"/>
  </xsl:function>
```

Then you can call it as `max(//date/mf:date(.))`: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexjii/2

If you really wanted to write a function to process a sequence of input items to return a sequence of `xs:date`s then use

```
  <xsl:function name="mf:dates" as="xs:date*">
      <xsl:param name="input" as="xs:string*"/>
      <xsl:sequence select="$input ! xs:date(substring(., 1, 10))"/>
  </xsl:function>
```

and call it with

```
 <xsl:value-of select="max(mf:dates(//date))"/>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexjii/3

As a syntax alternative, in XPath 3.1 you can use the arrow operator `=>`:

```
<xsl:value-of select="//date => mf:dates() => max()"/>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6rexjii/4

Comment: That worked a treat. Thank you!! Would you also please help me understand why my previous method failed? I'm trying to understand the xslt processing steps and why they produced the final error.

Comment: @justanotherchilli, well, for your direct XPath attempt you got the error message explaining that you can't call `substring` or `xs:date` on a sequence of items/nodes, just on a single one. How you do that I have shown in my answer, you can use `//foo/substring(...)` instead of `substring(//foo. ...)`. As for your attempt to write a user-defined function, keep in mind that `xsl:value-of` creates a text node of the value(s) selected in the `select` attribute expression, it does not return the value(s) selected, for that you have to use `xsl:sequence`.